# How to override navigational properties from base Entity Framework Core entity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

We have a few products which have some almost identical functionality, e.g. billing.

There is a nuget package with shared EF Core entities, something like:

```
public class InvoiceBase
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<InvoiceLineBase> Lines { get; set; }
}

public class InvoiceLineBase
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
    public InvoiceBase Invoice { get; set; }
}
```

Then each product can use that package and extend entities:

```
[Table("Invoices")]
public class Invoice : InvoiceBase
{
    public decimal Discount { get; set; }
}

[Table("InvoiceLines")]
public class InvoiceLine : InvoiceLineBase
{
    public bool IsPaid { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that return types for navigational properties also must be changed somehow in derived entities.

I have 4 example usages:

```
// in shared nuget package:
async Task CreateInvoiceInBaseRepository(InvoiceBase invoice)
{
    invoice.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;

    foreach (var invoiceLine in invoice.Lines)
    {
        invoiceLine.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
    }

    await dbContext.AddAsync(invoice);
    await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}

InvoiceBase GetInvoiceByIdInBaseRepository(int id)
{
    var invoice = dbContext.Invoices
        .Include(x => x.Lines)
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

    return invoice;
}

// in specific product
async Task CreateInvoiceInSpecializedRepository(Invoice invoice)
{
    decimal? discount = 5m;

    if (discount.HasValue)
    {
        invoice.Discount = discount.Value;
    }

    foreach (var invoiceLine in invoice.Lines)
    {
        invoiceLine.IsPaid = discount >= invoiceLine.Amount;
    }

    await CreateInvoiceInBaseRepository(invoice);
}

Invoice GetInvoiceByIdInSpecializedRepository(int id)
{
    var invoice = dbContext.Invoices
        .Include(x => x.Lines)
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

    return invoice;
}
```

First and seconds are used inside the package and 3rd and 4th are used in a specific product. During the creation I need to access and modify invoice's lines and during the read I need to tell EF to include invoice's lines.

My first attempt was to override `Lines` property in a derived class using `new` keyword:

```
// Invoice.cs
public new IEnumerable<InvoiceLine> Lines { get; set; }
```

But in this case EF doesn't use `Lines` property in a base class and hence first two base methods fail.

My another attempt was to manually map and cast `Lines` property in the derived class:

```
// Invoice.cs
 public new IEnumerable<InvoiceLine> Lines2 { get; set; }

 public override IEnumerable<InvoiceLineBase> Lines { get => Lines2; set => Lines2 = new List<InvoiceLine>(value.Cast<InvoiceLine>()); }
```

It almost worked: 2nd method failed because EF cannot include `Lines` property on a base entity. Also it looks terrible to have 2 different properties with different names for the same relationship.

I know that for this simple example it would be perfect to introduce generic type argument to `InvoiceBase` entity but in reality these entities have relations to other base entities like `Users`, `Subscriptions`, `PricePlans` and the list of generic arguments just becomes too big to deal with.

Is there another way to handle this? How to properly reuse entities and logic for them but keep the ability to slightly extend it?